# SQL MODEL- How to get rules to execute in correct order?

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, model

I have an SQL model with **3** dimensions and **5** rules.

I want the rules to execute in the following order:

```
rule1[1,any,1] 
rule2[1,any,1] 
rule3[1,any,1]
rule4[1,any,1]
rule5[1,any,1]
,
rule1[1,any,2] 
rule2[1,any,2] 
rule3[1,any,2]
rule4[1,any,2]
rule5[1,any,2]
...
rule1[1,any,n] 
rule2[1,any,n] 
rule3[1,any,n]
rule4[1,any,n]
rule5[1,any,n]
,
rule1[2,any,1] 
rule2[2,any,1] 
rule3[2,any,1]
rule4[2,any,1]
rule5[2,any,1]
,
rule1[2,any,2] 
rule2[2,any,2] 
rule3[2,any,2]
rule4[2,any,2]
rule5[2,any,2]
....
rule1[2,any,m] 
rule2[2,any,m] 
rule3[2,any,m]
rule4[2,any,m]
rule5[2,any,m]
. . . and so on . . .
```

I want the model to be able to handle tables that include all kinds of combinations of (dim1,dim2,dim3).

for example,

```
(1,dog,1), (1,dog,2), (1,dog,3)
```

all exist in a certain table being fed to the model, but

```
(1,dog,4), (2,dog,any)
```

Do not.

But I want the model to still work if I one day decided to feed it a table that DID include (1,dog,4) or (2,dog,1), etc.

How can we program the model to adapt to different sets of (dim1,dim2,dim3) combos?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing:

```
rules
iterate(360)
(

rule1[1+floor(iteration_number/20),any,1+mod(iteration_number,24)],
rule2[1+floor(iteration_number/20),any,1+mod(iteration_number,24)],
rule3[1+floor(iteration_number/20),any,1+mod(iteration_number,24)],
rule4[1+floor(iteration_number/20),any,1+mod(iteration_number,24)],
rule5[1+floor(iteration_number/20),any,1+mod(iteration_number,24)]

)
```

This works because I know dim1 is always less than 18 and dim3 is always less than 15 so the floor and mod functions give the desired rule execution order.